# High school thermodynamics question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

Here's the question:

**Two identical balloons are blown to the same size, one at sea-level and the other is at
the top of a mountain. Both balloons are at the same temperature. Which one of the
following statements is true?**

A) The samples of air confined in the balloons have the same pressure, but
different mass.

B) The samples of air confined in the balloons have the same mass, but
different pressure.

C) Both the mass and the pressure values of the two samples of air in the
balloons are equal.

D) Neither the values of mass nor the values of pressure of the two samples
of air in the balloons are equal.

What I thought of: if they're blown to the same size and both of them are at the same temperature, V and T are the same. Since pV/T is constant and V and T are the same in both cases, p must also be equal. I had no idea what to do with mass. The right answer is D so there's something wrong with my thinking.

Comment: Why is pV/T constant?

Answer (score 1):

Quite silly mistake. Thanks to Chemomechanic, I realized that pV/T is only constant at a given mass and molar mass. Meaning:

p1V1 = (m1/M1)RT1

p2V2 = (m2/M2)RT2

We also know that p1 > p2 , V1=V2 , T1=T2 , M1=M2

Meaning:

VM/TR = m1/p1

and

VM/TR = m2/p2

Since p1 > p2 , m1 < m2 , meaning that pressure and mass is going to be different.